# How to keep dc-tableview.js (DC.js, data table) sorting after redraw / rerender?

Tags: javascript, datatables, dc.js

I have a [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) DC-Chart which can be filtered by other [DC.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) charts.

When I filter a DC-Chart and redraw / rerender the dc-tableview chart the sorting is always lost.

```
dc.redrawAll(renderGroup);
```

**Any ideas how to keep the sorting column and direction?**

Edit: If I have to reassign the sorting. I am not sure how to **get the current sorting of the table** as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I know is that I can **resort the table after filter was assigned** this way:

```
tableView1.sortBy(sortByColumnArray, sortByOrderArray);
tableView1.render(DC_group);
```

But I assume there is a property or something that dc-tableview does not always overwrite the chosen sorting...